# Reading and writing images with Mahotas

Tags: python, image-processing, mahotas

I'm trying to write an image with Mahotas and finding it strangely difficult.

```
img = mahotas.imread('foo.png', True)
mahotas.imsave('bar.png', img)
```

the error I'm gettings is:

```
ValueError: mahotas.freeimage: cannot write arrays of given type and shape.
```

I'm on OS X and used brew to install freeimage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Author of mahotas here. The error message is not ideal (will fix it), but here's what's happening.

The greyscale image is a floating point image (i.e., `img.dtype == numpy.float64`) and you cannot save floating point images as PNGs.

Convert to `numpy.uint8`:

```
mahotas.imsave('test.png', img.astype(numpy.uint8))
```

and it will work as expected.

Comment: np == numpy in case anyone was confused ;)

Comment: Tx. I improved the answer accordingly.